# Force the lid, open or closed?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

I encountered the poem below, which ends with *force the lid*. I recognize this phrase, but I'm not sure if it means forcing the lid closed, or forcing yourself inside. Or can it be both?

> A system is a big black box
>       Of which we can’t unlock the locks,
>       And all we can find out about
>       Is what goes in and what comes out.
>       Perceiving input-output pairs,
>       Related by parameters,
>       Permits us, sometimes, to relate
>       An input, output and a state.
>       If this relation’s good and stable
>       Then to predict we may be able,
>       But if this fails us—heaven forbid!
>       We’ll be compelled to force the lid!
>     —Kenneth Boulding

Comment: "Force", as a verb in the general context of physical objects, means to apply pressure to such that movement is achieved.  One might force a box open or force it closed.  But it seems to me that the above poem clearly means "force open".

Comment: [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/force) v trans sense 4.b clearly lists this sense:  To break down or open by force: force a lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A system is a big black box
>   Of which **we can’t unlock the locks**,

The problem is "how to unlock the box", not "how to keep it closed".

> But if this fails us—heaven forbid!
>   We’ll be compelled to force the lid!

So if all those methods fail, the only option left is *opening* the lid by force.